# Getting image data from Canvas in proper form for CarrierWave and S3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I've been trying to get images created in HTML5 Canvas to be added to the server via S3 in my Rails app.  I'm using CarrierWave and Fog, but I currently need the user to save the image locally and then upload it for addition to the website.  I'd rather have them be able to add the image directly.

I found the post at [save html5 canvas output to my rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115635/save-html5-canvas-output-to-my-rails-app) which has helped to a point.

I can use the hidden field to pick up the data in data_url format (with 'data:image/png;base64,' removed, but I'm at a loss as to how to convert it into proper (json?) format to be used by carrierwave/S3.

The last answer at [save html5 canvas output to my rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115635/save-html5-canvas-output-to-my-rails-app) has a possible solution, but it seems to me that there ought to be a way to keep that much calculation out of the controller.

I currently have this function in my js file:

```
    $('#btnCanvas').mousedown(function(convert)
      {
      var dataURL =  canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var data = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");

      $('#hiddenCanvas').val(data);
      });
```

Is it possible to add some code to this function to convert the data into the necessary format (replacing "data" in the last line with a new variable name for the appropriate data)?  If so, where can I find that code for conversion in javascript?

Or should I go the route of modifying the controller?  Or should I try a different approach?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.